# Mapping 2D image onto 3D Scan Data

Tags: python, texture-mapping, cad, open3d, 2d-3d-conversion

Given a 2D image of blade and its corresponding 3D Scan data in stl/ply/pcd format. Is it possible to map the 2D image onto the 3D scan data using python? Or is it possible that we extract the color information from the 2D Image and map the color texture onto the 3D scan data using python libraries?
I am working on a project where I want to localize the defect position on the blade, I have already implemented AI algorithm to locate the defect on the 2D image, but now I want to transfer this information to the 3D CAD Data.

Ps. I am new to handling 3D data, so any suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

1. if your 3d data means a point cloud data from a lidar device in one timestamp, you can calculate the transformation from your camera to your lidar and project your lidar to the image plane and get color. And you can reference code from [here](https://github.com/ClementPinard/SfmLearner-Pytorch/blob/f84ede08e5bab9f1d618629f91264f3e0acafeea/data/kitti_util.py#L83:5)
2. if your 3d was collected from stereo vision software, like `colmap`. There is also a pose relationship between images and the 3d model. You can make the same approach as situation 1.
3. the worst condition is that your model doesn't have any relative pose between the images and the 3d model. The solution is to calculate an `image-to-geometry` result. `image-to-geometry` methods will guess the 3d pose of the images relative to the 3d model.
4. if you only want to know how to map a texture to a 3d model. There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14084067/11128133).